# Change button height depending on width [Android]

Tags: android, xml, button

I have a problem with buttons in `Android Studio`.
I want some buttons to be square, and at the same time have a `non-fix width` based on `weight`. I mean this:

```
android:layout_width="0dip"
android:layout_weight="0.5"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

I have looked for answers here, but none of them worked for me. I know it is not possible to do it via `XML`, so I've tried with the `btn.getWidth()`, `btn.getLayoutParams().width`... in my Java code, but all of them `return 0` as value.

Any idea?

Comment: They return null because they don't get a size until they are drawn, which is after onResume() is called. You could however, specify a dimension resource which keeps the desired size of the square in dp and get the screen width to see how many would fit + spacing.

Comment: Thank you, but don't worry guys, I've found a more appropriate solution for my problem.
I will work with "layout-xlarge", so that I can configure different layouts according to the screen size in which it is displayed.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to set button size by code, you should do something like this (in your class that extends `Button`):

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

    int width = getMeasuredWidth();
    int height = width;
    heightMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(height, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);

    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);}
```

or

```
    @Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
{
    int width = getMeasuredWidth();
    int height = width;
    setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
}
```

But there are an better way: create square png for all dpis and set it as a background of your button.

Comment: The fact is I am already using a square png image as background... But then I add "wrap_content" to the height, and it is not square, it turns a rectangle higher than wider... I'l try your code later. TY

Answer (score 1):

Use the following listener:

```
ViewTreeObserver viewTreeObserver = view.getViewTreeObserver();
if (viewTreeObserver.isAlive()) {
viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
       view.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);

       //Here you can get and set the TextViews size.
    }
 });
}
```

You were getting 0's because at the time you checked the views weren't measured. To be sure that you'll get the actual view you can use this listener.

Comment: Wasn't this deemed extremely expensive to use and unstable because it can be collected at any time, even in between the check isAlive and the subsequent calls? I haven't tried it in a long time so I don't know its current state.

Comment: I haven't had any problems using it so far. About the excessive calls, that's the reason why I removed it on it's first call to global layout. I don't have any recent news about it either, but it's used in iosched app for the ObservableScrollView, so I'm assuming it's not so bad.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested code this code at my end. Just Before onCreate() ends. just write these lines.

```
Button button= (Button ) findViewById(R.id.button);
button.post(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                Log.e("",""+button.getHeight()+" "+button.getWidth());
            }
        });
```

If you have any query please let me know.

Comment: This works and prints the values, however, if I add (btnTopLeft.setHeight(btnTopLeft.getWidth());), nothing would happen